# Lucene Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, junit, lucene

I would like to do some unit testings on a lucene framework, but quite honestly I have no idea how to go about it. I can't seem to figure out the most basic of tasks such as:

1. Setting up a mock directory with MockDirectoryWrapper
2. Extending my jUnit test class with LuceneTestCase does not allow any of my tests to run
3. I want to simulate corrupt file errors, lockeddirectory errors etc. but i'm confused how to use the MockDirectoryWrapper to do these sort of things.

A resource with some tutorials or examples would be great. Google doesn't seem to find anything related to Lucene unit testing and although Lucene's website has great documentation, they offer nothing in terms of tutorials.

Normally I use a RAMDirectory and inject it into my lucene classes to perform unit tests on basic functions such as add a document to the index, or remove a document etc, which is great, but it does not allow me to test errors such as those I listed above.

I could create a physical directory test file, create the test directory and then delete one of the files to essentially corrupt it, but is there a way to do this as a mock without actually having to create the file on disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A simple example test is
   https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/main/lucene/core/src/test/org/apache/lucene/TestDemo.java
2. I dont know what you mean by 'tests dont run': but its absolutely critical you use the exact version of junit that is documented to work with your release:

For example, for 3.5:

> Depends on junit 4.7.x (not 4.6.x, not 4.8.x)

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_5/lucene/README.txt

Junit sometimes breaks backwards compatibility, its not our fault.

As far as more advanced stuff like simulating errors, you are going to have to look at the code or look at similar tests in Lucene. E.g. to fake a disk full error, just look at TestIndexWriterOnDiskFull to see how it does it.

Comment: It must be the version number of jUnit that is giving me the issues. I never even thought of that. I'm using eclipse and it ships with 4.8. Thanks again for the help though. That sample test really helped a lot.

Comment: yeah thats likely it. I think in the next version of lucene we will support 4.10... the problem is we have a little state machine in our base test class that ensures any setUp() calls super.setUp() and any tearDown() calls super.tearDown(), and junit 4.8+ changes things in such a way, that the listener we have receives events it didnt before... more info here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3762